# How to exclude citations in frontmatter from bibliography ordering using bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing, front-matter

In my PhD thesis I have to include a few pages in the `frontmatter` that disclose that some chapters have been published as papers, including citations to the papers. These citations then appear as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. since they are the first to be used.

As a result, in my introduction, the first citation ends up as `[5]`. Is there a way to force bibtex to actually start ordering my citations from the introduction (in `mainmatter`) so that these citations start at `[1]`, and those in the `frontmatter` are counted at the end?

I'm using the `unsrt` style with no extra packages, and the `report` document class.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: Does `\usepackage{notoccite}` take care of it?

Comment: But do you want to keep the [1], [2], etc. format for your publications section or you want them to appear as they would in the Bibliography section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
{\csname @fileswfalse\endcsname\cite{aaa}}
```

in your front matter and then

```
\nocite{aaa}
```

at the end.

This does a normal cite where you need it but stops it writing the bibcite line to the aux file. then you need a `\nocite` later to write to the aux file and get the entry put in the generated bibliography.

Comment: Thanks David, given that each of these citations appear somewhere else in the text, I technically don't need the `\nocite` at the end, but this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4):

You can modify `frontmatter` and `mainmatter` with the idea of David:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\@citexOrig\@citex
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
%     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}%
   \AtEndDocument{\nocite{#2}}%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{\LetLtxMacro\@citex\@citexOrig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
frontmatter Text \cite{article-full} and \cite{article-minimal}

\mainmatter
mainmatter Text \cite{book-full} and \cite{book-minimal}

\bibliography{xampl}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

Of course you can reach the same with a redefinition of `\cite`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\citeOrig\cite
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
 \renewcommand*\cite[2][]{%
   \ifx\relax#1\relax {\@fileswfalse\citeOrig{#2}}\else {\@fileswfalse\citeOrig[#1]{#2}}\fi%
    \AtEndDocument{\nocite{#2}}%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{\LetLtxMacro\cite\citeOrig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
frontmatter Text \cite{article-full} and \cite{article-minimal}

\mainmatter
mainmatter Text \cite{book-full} and \cite{book-minimal}

\bibliography{xampl}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

Both solution based on the idea provided by David.

Comment: Thanks Marco. I accepted David's answer above since it was the simpler of the two, but yours is ideal to add to my document class - saving other users the trouble of finding the same above trick.