# Make a preliminary chapter that does not modify the order of references in main

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, chapters

Using KOMA scrbook class, is there a way to make a preliminary chapter that uses the reference order as cited in the rest of the document. The idea is that the main starts with reference [1] in citation order, and make a summary or commentary chapter before the main that cites some sources in the order of the main. How can this be achieved?

Comment: A solution here will depend on the bibliography/citation setup you are using. Please show us a small example document that shows what you have at the moment.

Comment: Broadly speaking I can imagine that this is possible if we assume that in this special chapter you only cite works that are also cited elsewhere in your document. If there is a source you only cite in this special chapter, things are going to be much more difficult.

Comment: @moewe That is the case. I will only cite, things that will be cited in the main matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use `biblatex` as the tag suggests, you can locally (e.g. within `\begingroup...\endgroup`) set the `citerequest` boolean to false, then `biblatex` will not write citation requests to the `.bcf` file, which means the relevant citations do not influence the ordering. This approach assumes that all entries you cite while `citerequest` is false are cited in another part of the document where the `citerequest` is not turned off.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{Special Section}
\begingroup
\boolfalse{citerequest}
Lorem \autocite{worman}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
\endgroup

\section{Normal Section}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Special Section Lorem [2] ipsum [1] 1 Normal Section Lorem [1] ipsum [2] dolor [3]]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/639970/35864.

Comment: That seems to work thanks. One question why do you use `\autocite` and not `\cite`?

Comment: @Mauricio `\autocite` is a higher-level command whose exact behaviour can be controlled with the `autocite` package option. That command makes it easier to switch citation "styles" with one single setting.